# How to use BLOB constructor in flutter

Tags: flutter

Actually am sending form data to server, In service they are providing BLOB functionalaties in their web service. so please guide me how my object convert BLOB constructor and set to form Data in flutter

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***Uint8List*** type for BLOB type.